# How to find alpine packages corresponding to their debian equivalents?

Tags: debian, alpine-linux

For eg: is there an alpine package corresponding to apt-transport-https or software-properties-common?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

apt-transport-https, as the name suggests, is some extension to apt, Debian's package tool. Alpine is not any mere Debian derivate, it doesn't use apt, so it doesn't make any sense to install apt-transport-https on Alpine.

software-properties-common is another package related to Debian and apt.

Why do you (think that you) need these packages on Alpine?

Comment: I have an ansible script that installs these dependencies or packages on ubuntu to setup an environment and I need to write tasks which will setup the same environment on alpine os

Comment: Alpine is not Ubuntu, nor Debian, it’s very different linux distribution. So you can’t setup exactly the same environment. However, I’m quite sure that this (exactly the same _debian_ environment) is not what you actually _need_.

Comment: Another example is say l have installed libmozjs185-1.0 on ubuntu and want to install a similar package on alpine.. how do I do that

Comment: Unfortunately there’s no package for libmozjs (Spidermonkey) on Alpine (yet), so you can either [write one](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Creating_an_Alpine_package) or compile it from source.